# MVC3 Object with a Collection of Child Objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, object, nested-lists

I have an MVC3 Project in C#.Net.  I have Object1 with a list of Object2...

```
    //navigation Property(s)
    public virtual ICollection<Object2> Object2s { get; set; }
```

Object2 has an Object1 property and an Object1_Id property

```
    public int Object1_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Object1 Object1 { get; set; }
```

When I run the Index View for Object2 I get the message "Invalid column name 'Object1_Id1'".  Weird....it's looking for an automated column.  When I remove the Object1_Id from Object2, it does fine until I go to Save in the Create View.  It then throws an error message:

```
{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Object1_Id', table 'dbo.Object2'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

I'm sure I'm just missing an easy step.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Code-First approach?

Comment: @Watermark...yes...any ideas?  I can't modify the DB from code.  the admin has to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my question.  When I call the Create post action on my Object2 Controller, I retrieve the parent Object1, create a Guid for my new Object2, add the new Object2 to the Object1.Object2s collection, set Object1 state to modified, then save the db:

```
            var object1ToUpdate = db.Object1s.Where(
                    aObject1 => aObject1.Id.Equals(myId)
                ).Include(aObject1 => aObject1.Object2s).Single();
            string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Object2.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            object1ToUpdate.Object2s.Add(Object2);
            db.Entry(object1ToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use fluent API to make the adjustment. You can do this in your DB Context class. Look toward the bottom of the page of this link to see a sample of using fluent API.

http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
    public class ObjectContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Object1> Object1s{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Object2> Object2s{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Object2>()
                .HasOptional(o => o.Object1).WithRequired(o => o.Object2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood the relationship between your objects when I responded with this, but let me know what works and I'll edit the final answer to reflect it. You may have to swap out the Objects in the modelBuilder statement to get it to work exactly the way you want.